# Best PCB CAD export format mostly compatible for review and analysis softwares?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, simulation, emc

When I try to import a reference board file (.brd) into AEDT it asks for Cadence software dependent extracta.exe.

Is there any board file format for major review and analysis simulation software which is mostly compatible and does not need translation import?